# Should I keep the proportion of categories when executing an stratification?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk, naivebayes

I have 30,000 phrases categorized by sentiment.

I'm gonna use Naive Bayes.

Here's the proportion (sentiment -> number of phrases).

```
anger           98
boredom        157
empty          659
enthusiasm     522
fun           1088
happiness     2986
hate          1187
love          2068
neutral       6340
relief        1021
sadness       4828
surprise      1613
worry         7433
```

So, I have to split my dataset into train/test to execute my model, etc, right?

Should I keep the proportion of the categories when executing the stratification?

I mean, if I pick 30% for the test sample, should I keep 30% of each sentiment instead of 30% of the whole dataset?

I guess yes, but I would like to have a more experienced opinion.

And how would you do that? Anyone here know a better way of doing that instead of executing a python loop, testing which sentiment, calculate 30%, put in a dictionary etc?

Is there any Pandas trick to stratify by a category feature, keeping the proportion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I keep the proportion of the categories when executing the stratification?

You seem a little confused regarding the terminology; the very definition of *stratification* (or [stratified sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling)) is exactly to maintain the proportions, otherwise it is simple random sampling.

> if I pick 30% for the test sample, should I keep 30% of each sentiment instead of 30% of the whole dataset?

They are not contradictory, are they? If you keep 30% of each category, won't you end up with the 30% of your initial set?

> Is there any Pandas trick to stratify by a category feature, keeping the proportion?

Don't know about pandas, but scikit-learn (which I guess you are going to use next) [`model_selection.train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) includes such a `stratify` option:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                    stratify=y, 
                                                    test_size=0.3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!